# Embedding SQLServer CE in an installer

Tags: sql-server-ce

We need to embbed SQLServer CE in the installer of our application in order to set it as the default backend. Is there any merge module or something to include the SQLServer CE installer in our installer? Or is it as simple as including the dlls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just include the DLL in the correct folder, and prepare app.config - see this blog post:
http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: That's not appropriate for us, since we don't use ADO.NET as-is, we provide several backends and we don't define an app.config file. 
Also, it seems that including the dlls directly is not enough. 

`Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8080. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinaries()`

Doesn't it exist a merge module to include in our installer?

Comment: Well, it's as easy as adding the dlls copied when installing SQL Server CE. We didn't need any app.config. Thanks!